# Ideas needed - jqGrid double postback kills viewstates. How to preserve them?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, postback

I have a jqGrid for .Net forms and the person who is involved had wanted it done so a license was already in place.

There are other things going on in the page that puts data into a ViewState.  Because of the double postback the viewstate will be wiped out in the second postback. We cannot put the information into a session because there is an option where the user could "open in a new window" and hence the session information will not be "separate" as if it was done in a ViewState which is specific to page.

I'm trying to think of a way to preserve the viewstate somehow on the double postback and make it unique for a page.

I was thinking of maybe having a session associated with a GUID but that would carry on through the pages and if I had to update the viewstates in the session it may get ugly.

I was hoping that maybe if I ask here there may be some ideas that I could use. 
Thanks

Comment: We decided to go with session instead and deal with other form variables in other ways.  

But...any suggestions are still welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Just venting. Damn it. I think the guy who wanted to go with jqGrid should have done a better job evaluating it. The double postback kills everything!  We have the grid on a form where the user can enter values.  WHen the user hits "save", the double postback effectively kills all the form field values. 

They definitely should have done a better job with this.